# Changing Hyundai Elantra power steering fluid

Tags: power-steering, hyundai, elantra

I have a Hyundai Elantra 2002 with 84K miles and would like to change the power steering fluid using a turkey baster. (1) I was wondering how much power steering fluid I need for my car? the user manual does not say anything about it. (2) The manual says I need the PSF-3 type for my car. PSF-3 is not found any where. So, I went to O'Reily Auto parts and bought the power steering fluid made by O'Reily. Is it good enough?

Comment: I did a few days past, and I used 2 quarts.

Answer (score 2):

Is that all the manual says? I believe you can use Dexron ATF, which is reddish in color. I would verify though, as PSF-3 is no longer made.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot properly change your Power Steering fluid with a Turkey baster! Your Power Steering System contains much more fluid than what is in the Reservoir. I usually remove a hose on the return side of the pump and allow it to pump itself dry( a few turns of the Steering wheel will do that) then refill the system whilst having an assistant move the steering wheel lock to lock as is possible. I would have no idea as to the amount of fluid you would need as every system is different but I would have at least a quart to 1.5 quarts(2 liters)on hand. You can never have too much but too little may spell danger(so to speak).

Answer (score 0):

Aminfar,

I have a 2002 Hyundai Elantra GLS with 75k miles, which I actually just purchased recently. I am not a mechanic, but when I called about replacing power steering in my Hyundai I was suggested Prestone Power Steering Fluid (which I picked up at my local Autozone). My mechanic friend told me Prestone is the next best thing since they don't make PSF-3 anymore. Got it for around $7.00, and I topped it off and I'm not hearing any problems. Just took a trip for 600 miles and it was smooth sailing. Planning to flush it out since it's past due for an actual flush. Hope this helps.